# Prove the number of expected nodes in a Binary Tree using Mathematical Induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation, computer-science

The following random process constructs a Binary Search Tree:

```
Generate(array[x:y])
{
 if(x==y):
  the root is x
 else: 
  pick a number (r) as the root
  Generate(array[x:r - 1])
  Generate(array[r + 1:y])
}
```

Let (a<sub>n</sub>) be the expected number of nodes that have two children in the tree with (n)-nodes generated.

Prove:

> a<sub>n</sub> = $\frac{n-2}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a_{i}+a_{n-i-1})$

using **Mathematical Induction**

I have no idea where to start, as I don't even know how to construct a proper equation to carry on the proof. Any *help* is appreciated or even where to begin!

Comment: What is MI?????

Comment: mathematical induction. I am sorry